# Where to ask a question about visual studio ASP.net sql database debugging?

Tags: discussion

Is there a stack overflow website (or anywhere) where questions can be asked about asp.net development?

I just posted one and it got deleted, sorry I thought this was stack overflow??

Comment: We need a little more detail to know what exactly you'd be asking. Yes, Stack Overflow is the site to ask questions about programming problems you face, but there are certain aspects of that which do not fit into our site very well. Can you be a bit more specific on what you wish to ask about?

Comment: Then follow Brad's advice and reask the question that was deleted on Stack Overflow itself and not on Meta. _This_ question is in the right place, as you're asking about the use of the site/network. A programming question belongs not on Meta Stack Overflow, but on regular Stack Overflow. As to the part in your duplicate of this about the question being "offensive," that's not why it was deleted. It was deleted only because you asked a programming question on Meta, which is off-topic. If you had asked it on Stack Overflow itself, it would likely not have been deleted like that.

Comment: I looked at the question that was moved, and that question was asking _where to ask_ the programming question, which doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Take your original programming question that was deleted, the one Brad links to in his answer, and ask _that_ on Stack Overflow. That's what we're meaning. Note that you may have to wait a few minutes, as I believe on Stack Overflow you're limited to one question every 90 minutes. But that will just give you time to check over your question and see if you have any typos or you're missing any information that may help get you an answer.

Comment: Check over as in read over your question a couple times for grammar, formatting, and spelling. Also, while you've got the time, looking over and applying the tips from the [ask] page might help you get a warmer response and better answers to your question when you post it. As for asking if a question can be asked there, that's nice and all, but it's not a programming question and therefore doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. To ask if a question belongs on the main site, you go to the Meta site (here) and ask- Which you did and were told the programming question does belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let me explain it this way: If you have a question about the Stack Overflow site itself, such as where to ask a question or how to use a feature, you use [this link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to ask it. If you have a question about a programming problem you have encountered, you would instead [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to ask. Hopefully that helps clear up any further confusion you have right now.

Comment: No, Max, you _are_ a bit lost and confused here. The URL for your original question starts with `http://meta.stackoverflow.com` which is for the _Meta_ site. This question was deleted as programming questions _do not belong_ on the Meta site. You then posted a rant answer on an unrelated question, which was deleted. At that point, you asked _this_ question, _which is in the correct place._ You then asked _another_ question about where to ask the programming question, but you asked it on Stack Overflow itself. It was (correctly) migrated here as it is not a programming question. (cont.)

Comment: As you had already asked _this_ question about where to ask your _original and deleted programming question,_ Brad (once again, correctly) merged that question with this one. What we are telling you is to go back to the original programming question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296371) and use [this link to the _Stack Overflow_ ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to ask your original programming question.

Comment: @MaxPower you should really take the advice given earlier by Kendra: read everything in [the help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the content found when you follow the links at the end of that topic. The three questions you asked can use more attention from you. Consider going over some of the stuff in  [one of the existing video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDBBFaqYTcl_4_AqIFmn9J8uICwMMdiP8)

Answer (score 4):

I deleted [your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296371/asp-net-app-in-debug-mode-has-constant-web-activity) because it was a programming question posted to *Meta* Stack Overflow (note the different title at the top of the page). Meta Stack Overflow is for questions about Stack Overflow, not programming questions themselves.

You'll want to ask on [Stack Overflow itself](http://stackoverflow.com) if you have a programming question.

Comment: @MaxPower - Just ask your original question on Stack Overflow. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712409/asp-net-visual-studio-debugging-where-to-ask was still the same as the above, asking where to ask the question, so it was migrated and merged with this one.